# Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' MYSQL UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: mysql, server

am trying to deploy a website on a new server I install MYSQL using the command

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

After that I try to access the MYSQL command prompt using the command

`sudo mysql -u root -p`

it is giving me the error:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password(NO)`.

Any idea on how to solve this? thanks!!

Comment: i also try the command ```mysql -u root -p ``` and press enter twice

Comment: you can't access root user in mysql without sudo. maybe this will help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have first to run

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

after that you should have entered a password for root and the server is configured.

You can also use after that

```
 sudo mysql
```

to get access with administrator rights and change passwords or add new users

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` command - which is the MySQL client library - doesn't require root privileges.

You should run it without `sudo`:
`mysql -u root -p`.

Then you should be asked to enter the password. As [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/) say, the password should be known to you:

> For installations using the MySQL APT repository or Debian packages directly downloaded from Oracle, you should have already assigned the root password yourself.

Comment: i also try the command ```mysql -u root -p ``` and press enter twice